# Why do we need to transmit in a cable with a digital modulation? Can't we just put high voltage for 1 and no voltage for 0?

Tags: analog, cables, digital-communications, modulation, digital-modulation

We know that we can't transmit a square wave pulse via EM and we need to convert it to an analog signal via some modulation.

But why can't we just put high voltage in the cable to represent bit 1 and no voltage for 0? This way I am not transmitting the pulse which has infinite bandwidth, but I am just putting the cable to high voltage to represent the bit 1 and viceversa for 0.

What is the downside/problem?

Comment: What cable? Your question is not clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you change the voltage to low vs high, that *is* a pulse. Can you elaborate on what you mean here?

Comment: @nanofarad doesn't destination "reads" a high voltage level so he knows it's a bit 1, and then if "reads" no voltage, it means that it's a 0. am I wrong?

Comment: @allexj That is not wrong, that is how most simplest data transfers still work. But when you try to send e.g. 12 million bits per second, they are pulses alright. You don't necessarily **need** modulation, but it may **allow** you to send data better, such as many gigabits per second.

Comment: @Justme can you tell me some names of these simple transfers? anyway, I don't have clear why even if I am transmitting 12 million bits per seconds, if destination is also receiving synchronized in time 12 million bits per seconds in that way that I wrote, then I don't understand the problem. That's because I am new to this world and I can't imagine it. can you explain me better?

Comment: @allexj We don't know why you don't see the problem. Perhaps you should explain why you think there is no problem so we can say what is wrong with that. For example, if you send bit string of 0101010101, why do you think the signal does not have pulses? In voltage terms that looks like square wave of lo-hi-lo-hi etc.

Comment: @Justme yeah I get that that sequence it's litterally a an alternance of square waves. but I'm just thinking at this situation: if I put high voltage in a cable, the destination will immediately notice high voltage so takes note that it's a 1, then if sender removes voltage then receiver understands that it must be a 0, then if sender again puts the voltage receiver knows it's a 1 etc etc. I'm just think about this very simple scenario. but I must have oversimplifying something I guess?....

Comment: also, if you say that I don't need modulation, then why you say that they are actually square waves so it's a problem. so I don't get: can I NOT use modulation? even if "that is how most simplest data transfers still work".... also if you could send me some names of these transmission I thank you :)

Comment: @allexj Some names of serial bit streams in wired communication: RS232, RS485, NRZ, Manchester encoding. You need to think about cable length, data rate, and perhaps impedance control of the cable.. Cables have finite bandwidth.

Comment: @allexj You have already described the most simplest modulation for transmitting bit-serial data streams -  i.e. no modulation. You can do that, it's been used in telegraphs sending morse code, i.e. high voltage draws black ink on paper, no voltage draws no black ink, or high voltage emits a tone, and no voltage emits no tone. Still used today in billions of devices sending serial data inside and between electronic devices. So what is the question really about?

Comment: how much less performant are these non-modulation communication compared to the more used FSK,ASK,PSK? just to have an idea

Comment: @allexj, 1. No cable transmits the input voltage "immediately" from the source end to the receiver end 2. No receiver can detect a voltage change "immediately" either. There are delays in both of these processes. 3. The main advantage of modulation is ability to have multiple channels on a single cable, not "higher performance" (although there may be some advantage in noise, depending on engineering details).

Comment: @ThePhoton what are these delays? is the speed of light? what else?

Comment: @allexj the speed of light (in the cable dielectric) limits the delay in the cable. The necessity to accumulate sufficient energy per bit to distinguish 1's from 0's is one thing that limits the speed of the receiver.

Comment: Electric signals travel in cable at about two-thirds of speed of light. And the transitions between "voltage" and "no voltage" cannot be straight edges, because infinitely fast edges need infinite energy to transition in no time at all. It's like tungsten light bulbs turn signals, you see them being on or off, but also slowly transitioning between on and off, and there is a limit how fast you can try to blink them because it cannot reach fully on or fully off state.

Comment: ASK, PSK and FSK use a carrier that could itself be modulated by another encoding. I discuss QAM at some length. For CATV work, the baseband QAM signal AM-modulates a carrier with a suppressed sideband to form a 6MHz TV channel. Because QAM encodes more than one bit per symbol, throughput is substantially increased over just binary (NRZ) coding.

Answer (score 6):

[The Queen:] This way I am not transmitting the pulse which has infinite bandwidth, ...

[Whole audience:] **Oh, yes you are!**

[image]

*Animation by Lucas Vieira. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fourier_transform_time_and_frequency_domains.gif).*

This Fourier transform animation demonstrates that the more square the waveform gets the more high frequency components it contains. A perfect square wave does indeed require infinite bandwidth!

Answer (score 3):

> But why can't we just put high voltage in the cable to represent bit 1 and no voltage for 0?

We can. Baseband signaling is used all the time. It's used in serial data transmission, Ethernet, between gates within a microprocessor, between chips on circuit boards, etc.

> What is the downside/problem?

The main downside is with baseband you only get one channel per wire. With modulation you can send multiple messages simultaneously on the same wire with different carrier or center frequencies.

Comment: I would also add that even within a 'carrier' (or baseband for that matter) you can send more than one bit per symbol. PAM-4 for example.

Comment: @hacktastical, but we can also do PAM-4 at baseband, so that's not something that distinguishes modulated signals from baseband.

Comment: I suppose QAM would be a better example of a modulation scheme that works in baseband or over a carrier.

Comment: @hacktastical, sorry, how do you get a quadrature signal at baseband?

Comment: For two channels A and B, A(t)sin(wt)+B(t)cos(wt). A and B represent constellation coordinates.

Comment: @hacktastical, but if we're using sin and cos at some frequency w to produce two channels, isn't that a modulated signal and not baseband?

Comment: Ethernet, any form, can hardly be used as an example of baseband communications (not counting MII/RMII). 10Mbps is Manchester coded, 100Mbps is encoded with 8b10b and MLT-3, gigabit uses TCM and 4D-PAM5.

Comment: @Justme, Manchester and 8b10b eliminate very low frequency and DC content, but they don't push the signal up to a (selectable) carrier frequency or allow multiple channels on a wire. And they don't shift the negative frequency components up into the positive frequency range. They're encoding, not modulation.

Comment: I'm drawing a distinction between a signal sent over an RF carrier (as would be done with QAM sent over a cable TV channel) and what drives the exciter (the sin/cos QAM.) Yes, there is a reference signal that makes the basic QAM symbol rate, and its two phases are modulated by A and B to make the composite QAM signal. But its bandwidth is 0 ~ symbol rate, rather than being centered on a carrier. So it's 'baseband'. Same relationship as CVBS video has to an RF TV channel.

Comment: @hacktastical And same relationship how baseband YUV has the UV colour signals QAM modulated in the CVBS.

Comment: Yes indeed, U and V (I and Q...) use QAM, occupying that 3.58MHz slice above 0Hz in baseband. But, it's still part of what gets fed to the exciter, not what happens within the exciter itself, so baseband.

Answer (score 3):

If your information never changes, you require zero bandwidth to send it.

If your information does change, then you need some bandwidth to send that change, even if it's just a single one-and-done transition from 0 to 1. (That kind of encoding is is commonly known as Non-Return-To-Zero coding, or NRZ. We'll come back to this.)

The rate at which you can reliably send information is defined by two things: the bandwidth of your link, and that link's signal-to-noise ratio. This is Shannon's Channel Capacity Theorem, expressed as follows:

- Capacity = Bandwidth * log2(1+SNR) (in bits/s)

Read more here: https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2008/04/channel-capacity/

Square waves require infinite bandwidth to send (they have an infinite Fourier series). So in real life digital binary signals have rounded edges, they're not perfect 'square waves'.

Using simple binary coding, namely, NRZ, we can tolerate a pretty crappy SNR but we need lots of bandwidth. In fact NRZ sent 'DDR' style sends two bits / Hz (1 bit per symbol.) For example, to send 10 MBit/s as NRZ we need at least 5 MHz bandwidth.

To make the NRZ signal 'fit' in 5MHz we have to carefully control its rise and fall time, and perhaps even filter the signal with a low-pass filter. In the real world, we'd need a bit more than 5 MHz to overcome limitations due to imperfect filtering, signal integrity, and noise. We might also use some form of pre-emphasis or cable equalization to improve the SNR of the channel.

Can we *always* just use NRZ? Well, not practically. NRZ is fine for a local connection, like from a CPU to memory, or for a longer, low-speed connection like a UART. It's even used for PCI Express, USB SuperSpeed, SATA, HDMI, Displayport, and many other serial short-haul connections.

When the distances get longer, or we're sending data over RF, we have to work a bit harder to make better use of channel bandwidth and SNR. We can do this by addressing signal integrity and equalization (as is done with HDMI, SATA and other serdes standards), but more importantly for this discussion, we can choose to code the data more intelligently to make better use of the channel, that is, closer to its Shannon limit.

This is where multi-level encoding comes in. We send more than one bit per *symbol* by defining more analog states than 1 and 0.

One multi-level coding you may have heard of is Quadrature Amplitude Modulation, or [QAM](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/QAM.html). QAM used for cable TV and other communication standards including wifi and satellite. QAM, like other multi-level encodings, uses less bandwidth for a given throughput than plain NRZ by encoding multiple bits per symbol.

QAM uses two reference signals offset 90 degrees from each other, called I and Q. I and Q are each modulated with multiple levels to form a grid of states, called a *constellation* that represents all the symbols possible.

QAM-256 for example encodes 16 different I and 16 different Q levels to make a constellation of 16x16 states, that is, 256 (2^8) unique states per symbol. So we say that QAM-256 sends 8 bits per symbol.

Using QAM-256, if we have 5 MHz to work with and better than 36-ish dB SNR, we can in theory send 5 Msym/sec for up to 40 Mbit/s over that channel. And in fact, cable TV QAM-256 comes pretty close to that, at 38.8Mbit/s, including additional error correction overhead. [More details here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/broadband-cable/data-over-cable-service-interface-specifications-docsis/19220-data-thruput-docsis-world-19220.html).

That throughput beats what even the best NRZ could deliver in a 5MHz channel, that is, 10Mbit/s. So QAM-256 encoding is a win.

(Newer versions of DOSCIS support QAM-1024, 2048 and 4096, even higher orders are on the roadmap. [More here](https://webinabox.vtools.ieee.org/wibp_site_files/download/R50053?f=DOCSIS_3_1_overview19.pdf).)

QAM shows up in wifi too - it's one of the higher-rate coding techniques, up to a [staggering QAM-4096](https://www.tp-link.com/us/blog/733/wi-fi-7-fundamentals-what-is-4k-qam-/) these days.

Besides QAM, there are many other multi-level and multi-band coding techniques used to shove more data down a channel. I'll highlight a few here that you've likely encountered in your daily life:

- [PAM-4](https://www.edn.com/the-fundamentals-of-pam4/) (PCI Express Gen7, others)
- [PAM-5](https://www.edn.com/what-pam5-means-to-you/) (Gigabit Ethernet)
- [8-VSB](https://www.atsc.org/atsc-glossary/8-vsb/) (North American digital TV)
- [OFDM](https://www.techtarget.com/searchnetworking/definition/orthogonal-frequency-division-multiplexing) (many uses, including LTE cellular and DVB)

In short, sending data as actually-square waves isn't a thing: it's impossible without infinite bandwidth. At the very least, NRZ signals are rounded to the limits of the channel. To get more throughput you need to increase symbol bandwidth and / or number of bits per symbol, while minding the limits that [Claude Shannon](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/claude-e-shannon-founder/) told us about so long ago.